# Unity.MVC4 Doesn't Dispose()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I've installed the NuGet Unity.MVC4 package http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/ and have hooked it up the same as I would if I were using the Unity.MVC3 package.

My dependencies are getting resolved correctly, but when using the HierarchicalLifetimeManager, my object's Dispose() method is not called at the end of the request.

I've actually set up a simple project using Unity.MVC3 and Unity.MVC4, with the exact same Bootstrapper.cs code in both projects. On the MVC3 version, Dispose() is called; on the MVC4 version, it is not.

I'm registering my type like so

```
            container.RegisterType<ITest, Test>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

with a very simple Test class

```
    public interface ITest
{
    void Foo();
}

public class Test : IDisposable, ITest
{
    public Test()
    {

    }

    public void Foo()
    {

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

I don't think I'm doing anything incorrectly, but there appears to be some bug in the Unity.MVC4 package.

If anyone is successfully using that package, I'm curious how you got it to work.

Comment: Will investigate and see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution to this issue is to upgrade to [Unity3](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity/) and install the [Unity Bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) package. The Bootstrapper package includes `PerRequestLifetimeManager` which should be used in place of `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`. Once the integration is complete, `Dispose()` is called at the end of every HTTP request just as expected.

Note that the [newest Unity documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec38) suggests that `PerRequestLifetimeManager` should not be used at all unless absolutely necessary. (I believe, however, that it is still needed in some cases - for example, where you want to share a `DbContext` across all objects used during a single request.)

With this solution, Unity.MVC4 is no longer needed and can be uninstalled.

Comment: Glad you got sorted. It seems there is no need for our Unity.MVC4 package anymore.

Comment: @Oliver, the approaches of these two packages differs. Unity.MVC4 uses child containers and built-in `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` and I think it is clearer. Whereas "Unity Bootstrapper for ASP.NET" uses custom PerRequestLifetimeManager.

Comment: I will have a look into it again than, maybe there is place for both to exist.

Comment: I'm using PerRequestLifetimeManager to register my context in Unity: container.RegisterType<DbContext, EntitiesContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor()); - but the DbContext is never disposed in a per request basis. I also included this line in the RegisterTypes method: DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule)); but when I do that, the DbContext is disposed before the request ends. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a look at the code. We simply ported the Unity.MVC3 code from codeplex (http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) and re-bundled it up for MVC4.
We have not made any alterations to the code.

Unity.MVC4 makes use of the Unity package managed by Microsoft (http://nuget.org/packages/Unity/). The majority of the code is in Unity.

Are you running different Dot.Net versions? i.e 4.0 vs 4.5? There seems to be a pre-release Unity for DotNet 4.5.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5 but not sure how that would make any difference. I've switched to the Unity.MVC3 package instead (dll references only) and it's working fine now so I'll continue to use it.

Comment: For me too. Unity.MVC3 works okay while Unity.MVC4 doesn't call Dispose. Seems like there is something wrong with calling `PreApplicationStartCode.PreStart`. Calling that method from within my own `PreApplicationStartMethod` sorts this problem out.

Comment: An issue was found where the assembly info line [assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Unity.Mvc3.PreApplicationStartCode), "PreStart")] is missing in Unity.MVC4 causing items to not be disposed.
We are looking at uploading a fix soon.

Comment: @Anton great to hear. BradVin release a fix to handle the prestatcode. Thanks for pointing that out!